# Why does this set a compact?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, normed-spaces

Consider the following set in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$S = \{ x \ :\ \|x\| = 1 \}$$

Why is this set a compact? I don't know about closed, but it doesn't look bounded to me.

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$? Then $\mathbb{S}$ is the $n-1$ dim. sphere.

Comment: Could you try and explain what you think boundedness means/ what your definition is?

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: Shouldn't it be any vector with the **length** of $1$?

Comment: That is what it says. All vectors with norm $1$.

Comment: @JHance, for a moment I thought that bounded set is a set which can be "covered" by another set. That's obviously not the definition...

Comment: While ForestGump didn't say it in the nicest way, what I was trying to get at was that since boundedness is often defined as "contained in a ball of finite radius", a set like the above with a norm restriction in the definition is one of the easiest things to show is bounded.

Comment: @JHance, then I still don't get it; consider the simple case of $\mathbb{R}^2$. For every ball with a finite radius, I can give you a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ outside the ball with a length of $1$. Isn't it showing that the set is **unbounded**?

Comment: @Elimination You should better first read the definition of openess.. What does an existence of a point not in a set have to do with showing that the set is open?

Comment: JHance, you are right! Sorry about that Elimination, the set is automatically sayng it is bounded and you said that it doesn't look bounded, I thought it was a joke... now I understand your issue, like mvw commented, your issue is norm vs lenght (2-norm)...

Comment: Oh I see now where was my mistake (norm $\ne$ length). Thank you!

Comment: This is closed and bounded so by heine borel thm, it is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is bounded: a set $S$ is bounded if and only if there exist some $R>0$ such that $\| x \| \leq R$ for all $x \in S$. In your case, take $R=1$.

It is also closed because the norm is continuous, so your set is $\| \cdot \| ^{-1} (\{1\})$, the preimage of the set $\{1\}$, which is closed, and preimages of closed sets under continuous functions are themselves closed.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $S$ is the boundary of a certain ball.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe OP is asking whether the $S^{n-1}$ corresponding to arbitrary norm $||•||$ is closed in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is true for an arbitrary norm $||•||$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In general, in a finite-dimensional Banach space, every norm is equivalent.

Comment: I think that is indeed his problem: norm vs length (which he might see limited to the 2-norm). Which plays no topological role due to norm equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

Use Heine-Borel-Theorem to verify that $\mathbb{S} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \colon \| x \| = 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a $n-1$-dimensional sphere is compact.
The sphere is the inverse image of a one-point set under the continuous function $\| x \|$. Therefore, the sphere is closed. $\mathbb{S}$ is also bounded; therefore it is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the Heine-Borel Theorem?

> **Heine-Borel Theorem.** Let $K \subset \Bbb R^n$. Then $K$ is compact, if and only if $K$ is bounded and closed.

Now let'ts consider $$ S = \{ x \in \Bbb R^n \, : \, \Vert x \Vert = 1 \} \; \; .$$

Note, that $S = \partial \mathbb B(0, 1)$, i.e. $S$ is the boundary of the ball around the point $0 \in \Bbb R^n$ with radius $1$. Since $\partial \Bbb B(0, 1)$ is bounded and closed, $S$ is compact by Heine-Borel.

Answer (score -1):

$S$ is representing a boundary and it is an inverse image continuous function $||x||$
**Compact Set** is a subset of a topological space if for every open cover of there exists a finite subcover of.